# How do I go about finding some $f(x)$ that satisfies the following first-order DE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

$f'(\sin^2x) = \cos^2x + \tan^2x,\quad$ subject to $\quad0<x<1$

Many thanks.

Comment: I have seen this question before not so long ago on this site ..so voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $1 = \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$ and $\tan^2 x = \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$ So for $y = \sin^2 x$ we get:

$$f'(y) = (1-y) + \frac{1}{1-y}$$

for $y \in \text{Range}(\sin^2 x) = (0,1)$ this equation can be solved using straight forward integration (i.e. you're looking for an antiderivative of $f'(y)$.)

Answer (score 1):

$f'(\sin^2x) = \cos^2x + \tan^2x= (1-sin^2x)+(\frac{sin^2x}{1-sin^2x})$

$\implies f(sin^2x)=(sin^2x-\frac{1}{2}sin^4x)+(-sin^2x-ln(1-sin^2x))+C$

I hope I'm correct